# Differential Equation (First order with separable variable)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $\frac{dy}{dx}=xy^2$. Find the general solution of the differential equation.

My attempt,

$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}=x$

$\int \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2} dx=\int x dx $

$-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$

$y=-\frac{2}{x^2+2c}$

Why the given answer is $y=-\frac{2}{x^2+c}$? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant is arbitrary. You can equally well have $3c,-c$, or even a different letter, like $A$; they are all equivalent. The given answer has just chosen a simpler-looking form.